# Regex to match docblock for specific function

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match a docblock / phpdoc comment for a specific function.

For example, given the following class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I want to write a regex that can match the docblock for a specific method, identified by its name.

I've tried using a positive lookahead to match the function definition, but trying to match the `boot` method's docblock always selects from the `register` method's docblock:

```
(\h*/\*\*(.|\n)*\*/\n)(?=\h*.* boot)
```

Gives me:

[image: Regex is broken :sadface:]

I do want to capture the preceding whitespace before the opening of the comment, and the final newline before the line with the function definition.

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: Maybe... https://regex101.com/r/Lg5Fwy/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given example, you might use

```php
^\h*/\*\*(?:\R\h*\*.*)*\R\h*\*/\R(?=.*\bfunction boot\b)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\h*/\*\*` Match optional spaces and `/**`
- `(?:\R\h*\*.*)*` Match all following lines that start with optional spaces and `*`
- `\R\h*\*/` Match a newline, optional spaces and `*/`
- `\R` Match the last newline before the line with the function definition
- `(?=.*\bfunction boot\b)` Positive lookahead to assert `function boot` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kblDB1/1)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for!